# Can't filter MS access datetime field using short date

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, ms-access, datetime-format

I am trying to generate a crystal report for my program, apparently I wasn't able to filter those data which is in datetime format if i use "=" and not "> or <". 
my code goes something like this

```
dim x as string ="1/1/2014"
dim y as date
y=cdate(x)

select from [tblname] WHERE [datetime field]=#" & y &"#
```

the query won't yield any record assuming there is more than one record with 1/1/2014 date not unless i copy the actual datetime data stored in access or use the "> or <"

is there any way that i can format in my SQL query the datetime field to short date for easy comparison? because i believe the time stored is the reason why i can't filter it using "="

Answer (score 1):

This would be better as a parameter query.  But since I don't know how or if you can use an Access parameter query with Crystal Reports, I'll suggest you format the date value as *#yyyy-m-d#*.

```
"select from [tblname] WHERE [datetime field]=" & Format(y, "\#yyyy-m-d\#")
```

If you want to ignore time of day when matching `[datetime field]` to day `y`, you can use `DateValue([datetime field])` which gives you midnight of that date.

```
"select from [tblname] WHERE DateValue([datetime field])=" & Format(y, "\#yyyy-m-d\#")
```

However, if your table contains many rows, you don't want to evaluate `DateValue` for every row.  Instead you can do something like this, and it can utilize indexed retrieval for faster performance if `[datetime field]` is indexed.

```
"select from [tblname] WHERE [datetime field]>=" & Format(y, "\#yyyy-m-d\#") & " AND [datetime field]<" & Format(y + 1, "\#yyyy-m-d\#")
```

Comment: I would suggest also format the `datetime field` as they may be having issues with the time values. i.e. `1/1/2014 06:00:00 <> 1/1/2014`

Comment: @hansUp does formatting the parameter that way will get the record equal to the date specified regardless of the time? because again i can filter a record if i use "> and <"  but not gonna work if i use "=" sign which i believe because the time is not included in the query....I am really looking for something like the CONVERT function in sqln server where i can directly convert the datetime field to shortdate in a query but I am required to do it in access that's why I'm having trouble

Comment: No, that matches only midnight (time 0) of date `y`.  Still unsure exactly what you want, but I'll add to the answer.  Check back shortly to see if I got close enough to what you want.

Comment: @shadowjfaith actually I think the real issue is the time values that is why i can't use "=" sign. So how will I format the datetime field to shortdate in a query? Is there a way to do it?

Comment: @HansUp what i want is to get all the record equal to 1/12/2014 regardless of the time value.

Comment: @user3150180 as you can see by HansUp's edit this should get you what you want as it just matches the date and ignores the time of day (which is why `=` doesn't work). Please refer to http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/format.php for some time functions in Access. Also has a lot of useful information on the site regarding other functions.

Comment: will try to read and learn more about those time functions and work again on my project. Thanks for the replies, I'll be back if any progress made.