# Access VBA filtering SQL by short date on a long date/time field

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am having an issue getting criteria to work.  There is a related question on StackO here, but I have tried what's in it and it's still not working, so I'm asking my specific question.  Apologies if that's not technically kosher at StackO.
[Can't filter MS access datetime field using short date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20863041/cant-filter-ms-access-datetime-field-using-short-date)

I have a query that I need to have WHERE criteria based on an associate ID and the current day’s date.  But the field that has the current day’s date needs to be a long date and time field, so criteria for short date doesn’t work.  I have made this query in query design mode and it does exactly what I want:

```
SELECT tbl_Data.[#], AssocID, tsUpdated FROM tbl_Data WHERE AssocID = 4441 AND DateValue([tsUpdated])=Date()));
```

But when I do the equivalent in VBA, which I need to have this happen in, it does not work.  **Please note**, I have used `Date` in this vba version because according to [this](http://www.classanytime.com/mis333k/sjdatetime.html) website, `Date` will return current date:

```
Set FinishReport = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("qry_SessionReport", "SELECT tbl_Data.[#], AssocID, tsUpdated FROM tbl_Data WHERE AssocID = 4441 AND DateValue([tsUpdated])=Date”)
```

I have tried all kinds of syntax, and I have tried the answers from that StackO URL above, but nothing has worked.  Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: You have type-setting style quote `”` instead of plain quote `"` here: `DateValue([tsUpdated])=Date”)`  Change it to: `DateValue([tsUpdated])=Date")`  What happens with that change?  Does it work?  If not, is there an error message?

Comment: I have made sure the right quotes are used, still a problem.  the error that results is Runtime error '2471':  The expression you entered as a query parameter produced this error: 'Date'.  For what it's worth, when I debug, this line later down in the code is highlighted: `tCompleted = DCount("qry_SessionReport.[EC#]", "qry_SessionReport", "")`.  I think the problem lies within the query but that's what highlights, which is an operation I want to do based on the query.

Comment: ah sorry, i simplified my SQL statement in the original question to focus on the problem.  there is, in reality, an [EC#] field in the SQL statement, and it still gives that error

Answer (score 0):

For the querydef, I noticed you don't have the closing parenthesis for the Date() function in the SQL text. In the VBA editor, the function is listed as Date with no parenthesis but if you tried to use the Date() function in a query without the parenthesis Access would throw an error. Hope that helps!